# Visual Studio 2017 - How to Disable Auto Commit When I "Add Solution to Source Control"

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

With Visual Studio 2013 I didn't have this problem.

When I add my solution to Git Source Control (Right click -> Add Solution to Source Control) it automatically commits my project.

I don't want to do that because I want to set my own first commit message. I want to set "First Commit" (for example) instead of "Add Project Files" which is the default message from VS2017.

How can I disable auto commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than look into change how VS works, why not try to actually solve the problem you have. I can see at least two easy solutions that involve absolutely no VS behavior changes:

- create the git repo manually, `git init`, `git add`, `git commit`, so you're in absolute control over what happens
- Let VS create the repo, and then `git commit --amend` to change the message to your desired one.

Comment: Ty buddy, i followed the 2nd bullet and it worked!... But one more Question... can i revert (--amend) an very old commit and not the last one?